# Windows how to create an startup application?

Tags: windows

I have a webpage that I want to open every time I startup my pc. The webpage is password protected.

How do I create a desktop startup application, that runs every time the pc is turned on. And that login to the webpage and goes to full screen mode?

I am running windows 7. I now if I create a program that login to a webpage and goes to full screen mode. I can simply put it in the start map.

But how should I create the desktop program?

I am new to windows programming, but I know programring rails.

I haven't created any windows programs before.

I am hoping to get some tips which language it would be the easiest to create this little program with.

Comment: your application is desktop or web?

Comment: What's the purpose of doing that? Are you trying to create a terminal that is meant only to access that specific website? What if the user hits `Alt + F4`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a WinForms or WPF application and use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control. It's a .NET wrapper around Internet Explorer which allows you to embed into desktop applications. Depending on how your web application tracks authenticated users you could use the following overload of the [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161356.aspx) method which allows you to send a POST request to a web page and provide the contents of this POST request (such as username and password in your example). This way you will be able to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than making one very specific program to do this, it is normally better to do this in two parts:

1. Choose an existing program (Browser) or write a program that does the basic UI that is needed.
2. Install it as the shell for a dedicated user account - essentially turning the user account into a "kiosk mode".

[KB555463](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555463) details the basics of installing IE as the kiosk application.

Answer (score 0):

Add a web browser to Startup Programs and set its default home page to your password protected webpage.

Comment: I need to automatic login to the password protected website and go full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you know hook with C/C++, then you can write a small application which run web browser and paste user/pass in the right textbox by finding it ID. 
If not, you should try the way Darin mentions above,use c# and webbrowser control.

Comment: `hook with C/C++` <-- what is this? Installing a system-wide hook is not going to do you any good in this situation.